# Is there anyway to return value when not found in findby jpa repository

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, repository

I have create a repository query. I want to response value when not found.

Here are my code:
in repository:

```
Optional<User> findByUsernameAndStatusFalse(String username);
```

in resource:

```
@GetMapping("/user/username/{username}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        Optional<User> user = userRepository.findByUsernameAndStatusFalse(username);
        return ResponseUtil.wrapOrNotFound(user);
    }
```

Comment: Are you looking to return a different User object? what do you want to return when it's not found? if you want to return another User then you can use Optional's `orElse()` or `orElseGet()`

Comment: I would leave the repository to return what is actually in the DB, and return default objects in your resource, as you are, or introduce another component which wraps your repository and provides those semantics. I would not change the behaviour of the repository from the default.

Comment: By the way, is that your actual code? The return value of `findByUsernameAndStatusFalse` is ignored.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`java.util.Optional#orElse`

this will return a default value if the optional doesnt have a value. example:

`User user = userRepository.findByUsernameAndStatusFalse(username).orElse(null);`

Answer (score 2):

You can use :

```
public ResponseEntity<User> getUser(@PathVariable String username) {
        User userExample = new User();
        userExample.setUsername(username);
        userExample.setStatus(false);
        User user = userRepository.findOne(Example.of(userExample)).orElseThrow(
    () -> new RuntimeException("Username not found" + username);
);
        return ResponseEntity.ok(user);
    }
```

***the above code i use findOne and pass an example to search for an object, when not found throws an exception***

**please add this method to controller**

```
    @ExceptionHandler(RuntimeException.class)
    public Map<String,Object> handleException(RuntimeException e) {
        Map<String,Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("status", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR.value());
        result.put("message", e.getMessage());
        return result;
    }
```

**When you add this code, all RuntimeException is thrown then api will return status as 500 and message is messgae of that Exception**